# Book series about a group of people transcending levels or circles of consciousness

Tags: story-identification

I believe this was a book from the early 80s.  A group of people worked to transcend through circles or levels of consciousness (I think 10 of them?) and it was part of at least a two-book series.

The group was small. Less than 20 people. My memory is fuzzy on the details but I know I read it sometime between 1986 and 1988. The goal was to get to an ultimate level and that was where the second book started.

Comment: Can you add any more detail? How big was the group? What were distinguishing features of the main characters? What conflicts arose? What did the cover of the book look like? Any thing at all could help someone answer.

Comment: The group was small. Less than 20 people. My memory is fuzzy on the details but I know I read it sometime between 1986 and 1988. The goal was to get to an ultimate level and that was where the second book started.

Comment: I'm reminded of "The New Minds" by Dan Morgan, book one of the "Sixth Perception" series, but it's been so long since I read them and the internet is unhelpful in this case.

Comment: Deepak Chopra wrote something like that in "The Return of Merlin". The description you gave is very close, although this book was published in 1997.

Answer (score -1):

The Celestine prophecy i believe was the book series.

Comment: Can you provide any more information on the story? Any details that relate to the points made by the asker?

Comment: To really answer the question,you need to explain the similarities between the story in the question and the one you propose as the answer.